# Equivalent Martingale Measure

Tags: statistics, finance

I'm finding it difficult to calculate the EMM as this problem comes with an interest earned on the account. How would I incoporate this into the working out?

Consider the following discrete time one-period market model. The savings account is 1 dollar at time 0, and 1.2 dollars at time 1. The stock price is given by S0 = 1 and S1 = alpha, where alpha is a random variable taking two possible values 1.3 and 0.8, each with positive probability.

a). Find with proof the EMM of this model. Does this model have arbitrage opportunities?

b). Consider a put option with exercise price K = 1 that expires at time 1. Find the replicating portfolio for this put option.

c). Compute the time 0 price of this unit option.

d). If the savings account at time 1 is $1.3 instead, does the model have an EMM?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Maybe you can explain first what you'd do if there's no interest earned on the account and what you think changes fundamentally when there is?